# PDO handle value types (int or varchar)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This foreach (see last code) with PDO execute statement works great when "value" is a varchar (database column type is set to -> varchar(255)) like "Bush" or "Obama":

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recid] => 1
            [lname] => Bush
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [recid] => 2
            [lname] => Obama
        )

)
```

But when the "value" gets a number like "58" or "65" (database column type is set to -> int(11)) the UPDATE statement fails and nothing gets updated to the database.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [recid] => 1
            [age] => 58
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [recid] => 2
            [age] => 65
        )

)
```

code to get $_POST array and PDO execute statement:

```
foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $SubArray) {
    foreach ($SubArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'recid') continue;

        $sql  = "UPDATE clients SET $key = :value WHERE id = :recid";
        $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);

        try {
            $STH->execute(array(':value' => $value, ':recid' => $SubArray['recid']));

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $code = $e->getCode();
            $file = $e->getFile();
            $line = $e->getLine();
            $msg  = $e->getMessage();
            echo "$file:$line ERRNO:$code ERROR:$msg";
        }
    }
}
```

how can i fix this issue, that the database gets updated?

Comment: So I see you stuck to your one by one updates. Oh, poor language of PHP.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thats true. but i am learning more and more at every step ;-)

Comment: So I see, your codes become worse and worse with every step

Comment: @YourCommonSense and you also have any solution on this?

Comment: this is just impossible a case. I'd rather bet on some code inconsistency than PDO problem. I've never heard of PDO not inserting numbers.

Comment: @YourCommonSense it does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO MySQL Error - SQLSTATE \[42000\]: by UPDATE(ING) integer to table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586668/pdo-mysql-error-sqlstate-42000-by-updateing-integer-to-table)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

also at this question - the problem are the missing **backticks**.

setting up the query ($sql) like this, does the trick.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `clients` SET `$key` = :value WHERE id = :recid";
```

before and after table and column name use **backticks**

> `

Comment: To avoid answering your questions twice you have to avoid **asking** twice