# PDO MySQL Error - SQLSTATE [42000]: by UPDATE(ING) integer to table

Tags: mysql, pdo, php

I can update text strings (`varchar`) types to my Mysql database with PDO without any problems. but with integer (`int(11)`) types - my PDOstatement has some big problems and also can not write the integer value to the database.

here you can see the error message I get by putting integer values for UPDATE:

> ERRNO:42000 ERROR:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'age = '800' WHERE id = '1'' at line 1

I am getting the values from `$_POST` like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['changed'] as $SubArray) {
    foreach ($SubArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'recid') continue;


        $sql  = "UPDATE clients SET $key = :value WHERE id = :recid";

        $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);

        try {

            $STH->execute(array(':value' => $value, ':recid' => $SubArray['recid']));

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $code = $e->getCode();
            $file = $e->getFile();
            $line = $e->getLine();
            $msg  = $e->getMessage();
            echo "$file:$line ERRNO:$code ERROR:$msg";
        }
    }
}
```

echo urlencode($sql) => `UPDATE+clients+SET+age+%3D+%3Avalue+WHERE+id+%3D+%3Arecid`

Comment: Have you made sure that the type for the column in the database is set to Integer?

Comment: Have you done what the error message suggested to you? Have you consulted the Mysql manual of your server version? What did you find out?

Comment: A syntax error has nothing to do with binding. It's a problem with the query. What about echoing your query out for the visual inspection?

Comment: i thought PDO does automatic placeholder escaping? what would be a solution to automate the placeholder escaping? and yes the database column is set to integer.

Comment: it is not about escaping

Comment: Could you please echo your $sql out and add it to your question? I tried hard to reproduce this error but in vain.

Comment: better make it urlencode($sql);

Comment: i add the $sql echo to my question.

Comment: wait. what is that? I mean **real** $sql variable. and better urlencode()-d to reveal all possible non-printable characters

Comment: now it should be the **real** $sql variable

Comment: thanks. nothing wrong with this query...

Comment: okay, if you run this code, what does it say? `$DBH->query("UPDATE kunden SET age = '800' WHERE id = '1'");`

Comment: @YourCommonSense i have a working solution - what do you say to this solution?

Comment: this query you posted here is not a real one, right? you have changed `kunden` to `clients` right here, and you have changed something to "age". What it was?

Comment: It would seem one of your column names is a reserved word. Consult the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) to see what words are reserved. For maximum compatibility, you should *always* wrap MySQL table and column names in backticks (other engines have their own mechanisms for this). Note: since you haven't updated your PHP code sample, we cannot see how/where you are logging `$sql`, so there is no real guarantee that you logged the query that actually crashed.

Comment: please, see my answer - its working with the **backticks**

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be, my comment just tries to explain why it works that way and why it took so long to get here.

Comment: @Mike, so the problem was not with the code but with the way you ask. So, please in the future **always post the actual code, do not edit it an any way**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting up the query ($sql) like this, does the trick.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `clients` SET `$key` = :value WHERE id = :recid";
```

before and after table and column name use **backticks**

> `